# winforms кнопка не меняет фон при наведении

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть форма с кнопкой на windows forms, при наведении на которую фон кнопки должен изменяться, но фон меняеться только после того, как я убираю указатель мыши. Код ниже и скрин работы ниже

```
  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        exit.MouseEnter += (s, e) => { exit.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(72, 72, 72); };
        
        
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если кидаете код, то только текстом, не на скриншоте.

Comment: Данный код должен работать, удостоверьтесь что это именно та кнопка и вы нигде её не пересоздаёте, удостоверьтесь что другие события на кнопке не мешают, уберите временно ваши winapi функции, никто не знает что и как вы там используете, разнесите MouseEnter на несколько строк и поставьте внутрь точку останова перед примением цвета. Если ничего не поможет - сделайте нормально метод MouseEnter через IDE.

Comment: PS а почему вы решили что код не работает? Если эта та кнопка с крестиком - то она именно серая как и нужно. Если вам нужно  чтобы она меняла свой окрас обратно - добавляйте MouseLeave.

Comment: WinAPI висит на панеле, а не на кнопке и на кнопку это никак не влияет. Кнопка должна становиться серой ПРИ наведении, а не после того, как курсор покинул область кнопки(а у меня как раз такой случай). Ошибок с именем нет

Comment: Но если сменить flat style на default, то всё ок, но мне нужен flat style с свойством flat

Comment: Это отлично что вы нашли лучшее решение. Однако, родительские контролы ещё как могут влиять на дочерние, например, если вы поменяете у формы BackColor - дочерняя кнопка ещё как унаследует это изменение. Фреймворк может подкинуть немало сюрпризов, нежиданные влияния возможны там где не ожидаешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для flat style нужно использовать FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor:
exit.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor= Color.FromArgb(72, 72, 72);